# Why do Hindus give the bhoz (party) after someone's death?

Tags: rituals, culture, death, sraddha

I am a Hindu but sometimes I really think what is going on in our religion. Someone lost his family member and gave *bhoz* (party) to all the relatives and brahmins. Why is this happening in Hindu culture only?

Comment: It is done as per the rules laid down in our scriptures.Feeding anyone is not a crime anyway.And death in Sanatana Dharma is not seen as the end of everything .Its just a passage of the soul from one body to another.So,nothing to mourn about death for the Hindus.

Comment: These steps are followed to show two important things to the lost family.1.To overcome from the past and to begin the new one.(because the lost family members are unwilling to prepare food and eat them so in such case relatives are more helpful ) 2.To show the love of relatives. To overcome the family from the lost from these 10 days is the task for these kinds of steps.

Comment: Many cultures celebrate death as part of the cycle of life

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to *Garuda Purana*, it is said that when death occurs, the subtle body of a person leaves the gross body. Subtle body and his soul comes out and can see the servants of *Yama* and attendants of *Lord Vishnu* who are present there to take that person to *Yuma Loka*.

That Subtle body is almost the size of one's thumb. *After death rituals* get started at that time. The person should be cremated within 12 hours after death. And from the next day the ritual of *Pinda Daan* also gets started.

Lord Vishnu explains *Pindas* in "Garuda Purana". In the southern part of house, a pit is made and pindas are offered daily for ten days. These help to make a new body for the dead. On the tenth day the subtle body develops hunger. The subtle body itself is called as *Preta*. On Thirteenth day, the subtle body(Preta) starts its journey to Yumloka. So preta eats as much on this day. Family Offers a bhoj to the departed soul.

Comment: Welcome to Hi.SX. We encourage you to attribute citations (preferably online) for your answer; for example the verse, chapter etc.